# Question about integration by parts when we have a sum of integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the integral:
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_0^1\int_0^1g(x,y)dxdy \:+\:\int_0^1h(x)dx $$

I must integrate by parts with respect to $x$ the left side, $\int_0^1f(x)dx$.

Can I integrate by parts $\int_0^1\int_0^1g(x,y)dxdy$, then I integrate by parts $\int_0^1h(x)dx$ and just add the two together ?

Comment: Yes, you can work out the two integrals on the RHS separately, then add the results together

Comment: @JohnDoe This is nice property that I didn't know it's exists, thanks!